# Why do eps images do not show TexLive2014?

Tags: graphics, floats, xetex, eps, crop

I want insert my university logo that is .eps format with xelatex. but that do not show.
my TexLive version is 2014.

Why do eps images do not show TexLive2014?

Comment: They *do* show compiled with TL14's XeLaTeX. Can you post a minimal working example that is *not* working, please?

Comment: Without both a MWE and a place we can obtain the relevant EPS file we can't hope to answer here.

Answer (score 1):

XeLaTeX should handle eps files with non problem. But your eps file might contain extraneous material, suche a bitmapped screen preview of the real image.

Therefore try converting it into another acceptable format, for example pdf with ps2pdf and import the pdf image instead of the eps one.

Maybe that the extraneous material forbids a suitable transformation in another format. 
In that case you should open the eps file with a text editor (not by double clicking on its file name) and tray to examine the begining ot the file and the end of the file; normally the extraneous materia il before the %!PS label (generally in a line similar to this one: %!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-1.2); while the label %%EOF marks the end of the eps code.